# Return list of items in list greater than some value

Tags: python

I have the following list

```
j=[4,5,6,7,1,3,7,5]
```

What's the simplest way to return `[5,5,6,7,7]` being the elements in j greater or equal to 5?

Comment: and what will be the fastest?

Comment: for sure you should not sort them before filtering it. Since that will slow down a lot. Instead start filtering it, and then sort out the result if you need that sorted

Comment: NOTE for duplicate closers: for questions asking about *what the syntax means* for a list comprehension, consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475314.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to filter it:

```
j2 = [i for i in j if i >= 5]
```

If you actually want it sorted like your example was, you can use [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted):

```
j2 = sorted(i for i in j if i >= 5)
```

Or call `sort` on the final list:

```
j2 = [i for i in j if i >= 5]
j2.sort()
```

Comment: There's no need to use a list comprehension when you're going to feed it to `sorted` anyway. Hopefully you do know generator expressions and just forget how well they apply in that case ;)

Comment: @Michael that would be a nice addition though! :)

Comment: @delnan Oh, yes; I just copy/pasted the first line and wrapped it in `sorted()`. Fixed, thanks

Comment: @İsmail - `numpy` has a `where` function (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).  But in `numpy` you could also do `j2 = j[j >= 5]` if `j` is an ND array.

Answer (score 18):

A list comprehension is a simple approach:

```
j2 = [x for x in j if x >= 5]
```

Alternately, you can use `filter` for the exact same result:

```
j2 = filter(lambda x: x >= 5, j)
```

Note that the original list `j` is unmodified.

Answer (score 13):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
[x for x in j if x >= 5]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `filter` (short version without doing a function with `lambda`, using `__le__`):

```
j2 = filter((5).__le__, j)
```

Example (Python 3):

```
>>> j=[4,5,6,7,1,3,7,5]
>>> j2 = filter((5).__le__, j)
>>> j2
<filter object at 0x000000955D16DC18>
>>> list(j2)
[5, 6, 7, 7, 5]
>>>
```

Example (Python 2):

```
>>> j=[4,5,6,7,1,3,7,5]
>>> j2 = filter((5).__le__, j)
>>> j2
[5, 6, 7, 7, 5]
>>>
```

Use `__le__`. I recommend this. It's very easy. `__le__` is your friend.

If want to sort it to the desired output (both versions):

```
>>> j=[4,5,6,7,1,3,7,5]
>>> j2 = filter((5).__le__, j)
>>> sorted(j2)
[5, 5, 6, 7, 7]
>>>
```

Use `sorted`

#### Timings:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit(lambda: [i for i in j if i >= 5]) # Michael Mrozek
1.4558496298222325
>>> timeit(lambda: filter(lambda x: x >= 5, j)) # Justin Ardini
0.693048732089828
>>> timeit(lambda: filter((5).__le__, j)) # Mine
0.714461565831428
>>>
```

So [Justin wins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587915/return-list-of-items-in-list-greater-than-some-value/4587963#4587963)!!

With `number=1`:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit(lambda: [i for i in j if i >= 5],number=1) # Michael Mrozek
1.642193421957927e-05
>>> timeit(lambda: filter(lambda x: x >= 5, j),number=1) # Justin Ardini
3.421236300482633e-06
>>> timeit(lambda: filter((5).__le__, j),number=1) # Mine
1.8474676011237534e-05
>>>
```

So [Michael wins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587915/return-list-of-items-in-list-greater-than-some-value/4587920#4587920)!!

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit(lambda: [i for i in j if i >= 5],number=10) # Michael Mrozek
4.721306089550126e-05
>>> timeit(lambda: filter(lambda x: x >= 5, j),number=10) # Justin Ardini
1.0947956184281793e-05
>>> timeit(lambda: filter((5).__le__, j),number=10) # Mine
1.5053439710754901e-05
>>>
```

So Justin wins again!!

Comment: I think Justin won on the second one as well. 1.6*10^-5 is greater than 3.4*10^-6.

Answer (score 3):

In case you are considering using the [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) module, it makes this task very simple, as requested:

```
import numpy as np

j = np.array([4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 3, 7, 5])

j2 = np.sort(j[j >= 5])
```

The code inside of the brackets, `j >= 5`, produces a list of `True` or `False` values, which then serve as indices to select the desired values in `j`. Finally, we sort with the `sort` function built into NumPy.

Tested result (a NumPy array):

```
array([5, 5, 6, 7, 7])
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your desired output is sorted, you also need to sort it:

```
>>> j=[4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 3, 7, 5]
>>> sorted(x for x in j if x >= 5)
[5, 5, 6, 7, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way,

```
j3 = j2 > 4
print(j2[j3])
```

It was tested in [Python 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python#Version_3).

Comment: Do it really works? I got `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'`

Comment: Is this a response to previous answers? `j2` is a processed version of `j` in them. Can you [make](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53434704/edit) the code self-contained? But ****** ***without*** ****** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.