# How does this "x for x in..." construct work?

Tags: python

Can someone please explain in detail the below type of for loop?

```
primes = [x for x in range(2, 50) if x not in noprimes]
```

or

```
le_list = [i for i in getfiles(path) if i != 'fred']
```

The bit i dont get is the i for i, or x for x. I do not understand what its actually saying.

```
variable for variable in a list if variable whatever.
```

I dont see why you need variable twice at the start. The for loop goes through each item in list anyway, how is it treated differently?

Comment: I am surprised to see this (simple) question has never been asked before on Stack Overflow...

Comment: @MaximeLorant It had definitely been asked prior to this question, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475314) in 2011. It comes up all the time. However, the version of the question I have been establishing as canonical is newer than this one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason for the apparently redundant extra mention of the variable `x` when writing `x for x` is that the first `x` does not need to be `x`. It just happens to be in the examples you give. Here are a few more examples which should clarify the difference between the first and second `x` in your question:

```
ones = [1 for x in range(10)]
```

This simply gives a list of 10 ones, the same as `[1] * 10`.

```
squares = [x*x for x in range(10)]
```

This gives `x` squared for each `x` in the specified range.

In your example, the second `x` is the variable used by the for loop, and the first `x` is simply an expression, which happens in your case to be just `x`. The expression can be whatever you like, and does not need to be in terms of `x`.

---

```
results = [expression for x in range(10)]
```

`expression` can include anything you like - a string, a calculation, a function - whatever you choose. If the expression happens to be just `x` then it looks unusual if you are not used to it, but it's the same as the following:

```
results = []
for x in range(10):
    results.append(expression)
```

Answer (score 2):

The good way to understand it is to read it a bit different. So if we take your piece of code:

```
primes = [x for x in range(2, 50) if x not in noprimes]
```

We can read is as:

> Primes = All "x for" which "x in range(2,50)" but only "if x not in noprimes"

I hope this helps you understand the functionality better.

Answer (score 0):

It is a placeholder for a transformation of the element.

Suppose you wanted a list of primes multiplied by 2. Then you could replace the first `x` with `x*2`.

```
primes = [x*2 for x in range(2, 50) if x not in noprimes]
```

You write the following to say that you do not want a transformation, and just original `x`.

```
primes = [x for x in range(2, 50) if x not in noprimes]
```

---

**Another perspective**: Consider the `x` in the statement `primes.append(x)`. *That* is the same as the first `x` in the loop in your question. In fact, this is the **exact same loop** as the one above.

```
primes = []
for x in range(2,50):
   if x not in noprimes:
       primes.append(x)
```

Here is the other example, with `x*2`.

```
primes = []
for x in range(2,50):
   if x not in noprimes:
       primes.append(x*2)
```

Comment: still not following sorry, not sure what x^2 does either.

Comment: @githubphagocyte, Oops, I meant `**`. Fixing.

Comment: @githubphagocyte, I just changed it to simple multiplication to avoid complications about operators, since that is not the point of the example. Thanks for pointing that out. I have been writing too much `latex` and `R`.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is called a "comprehension" (e.g. list comprehension, dictionary comprehension, etc.). It's a compact way of specifying the contents of the list/dictionary/other data structure  programmatically. The [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) explain it pretty well.