# Need this code simplified please

Tags: python

so i just started learning python and found this 2 lines of code for finding multiple indexes of letters in strings/lists.
I'd love if some of you guys can simplify the 2nd line for me,

```
text= 'Allowed Hello Hollow'
print [n for n in xrange(len(text)) if text.find('ll', n) == n]
```

I don't know if it's just a shortcut style writing or something, but I'd like it simplified, thanks :D

Comment: Maybe try deconstructing the list comprehension (the `[n for n in ...]` part) into a `for` loop and see how it goes?

Comment: `l = [];
for n in xrange(len(text)):
      if text.find('ll', n) == n:
             l.append(n);` then `print l`

Comment: You should seriously consider learning Python 3, Python 2 will reach its official End Of Life in 2020.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the "simplified" version

```
myList = []
for n in xrange(len(text)) : 
    if(text.find('ll', n) == n) : 
        list.append(n)
print myList
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37869704/5712576) explains the syntax

Comment: I think you have an error. `xrange` is for python 2 but `print()` is for python 3. Make the code for python 2 or 3, but not something hybrid.

Comment: @EnderLook You can use parentheses with the `print` statement.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, oh, I didn't know that.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yes, you can use parentheses with the `print` statement, but it makes the code confusing, since the `print` _statement_ with parentheses prints a tuple, so it's rather different to calling the `print` _function_. However, in Python 2.6+ the `print` function is available via a future import: just put `from __future__ import print_function` as the first `import` statement of the script.

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name because that shadows the built-in `list` type. And you shouldn't do `print(some_stuff)` unless you're actually calling the print _function_.