# How to effectively iterate through CSV import

Tags: python, csv

Considering the code below, I am trying to understand why I don't get the same result when using

```
data=[row for row in reader]
```

as I would when doing the

```
data1.append([row])
```

with the loop that I tried below.

```
import csv 


path='/Users/johnfeldhausen/Documents/Python Practice/google_stocks.csv'
file=open(path,newline='')
reader= csv.reader(file)
reader1= csv.reader(file)
#reader is an iterable 

header=next(reader) #The first line is the header 

data=[row for row in reader]
print(data)

data1=[]
for row in reader1: 
    data1.append([row])

print(data1)
```

Comment: `[[row] for ...]`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe could you clarify please

Comment: What is unclear? Compare what you're doing in those two samples, and their outputs, then try applying the change I've suggested. If you still have an issue, give a [mre].

Comment: I am trying to understand what [row for row in reader] means but it looks like it got deleted from my question somehow. Also trying to understand how that compares to the attempted append approach. Your initial comment seemed to just replace what I already had listed in the code( which worked just fine)@jonrsharpe

Comment: If you're just unfamiliar with *list comprehensions*, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475314/python-for-in-loop-preceded-by-a-variable

Comment: okay thanks Jon. Do you have advice for how to search for things in general without being specific.. I saw in that post you attached "* for * in *", is that what you recommend using in the future to search if you don't know the term that aligns.. like you pointed out "list comprehensions" @jonrsharpe