# Selecting elements of a Python dictionary greater than a certain value

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I need to select elements of a dictionary of a certain value or greater. I am aware of how to do this with lists, *[Return list of items in list greater than some value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587915/return-list-of-items-in-list-greater-than-some-value)*.

But I am not sure how to translate that into something functional for a dictionary. I managed to get the tags that correspond (I think) to values greater than or equal to a number, but using the following gives only the tags:

```
[i for i in dict if dict.values() >= x]
```

Answer (score 56):

`.items()` will return `(key, value)` pairs that you can use to reconstruct a filtered `dict` using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that is feed into the [`dict()` constructor](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict), that will accept an iterable of `(key, value)` tuples aka. our list comprehension:

```
>>> d = dict(a=1, b=10, c=30, d=2)
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'c': 30, 'b': 10, 'd': 2}
>>> d = dict((k, v) for k, v in d.items() if v >= 10)
>>> d
{'c': 30, 'b': 10}
```

If you don't care about running your code on python older than version 2.7, see [@opatut answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18807154/484441) using ["dict comprehensions"](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
{k:v for (k,v) in dict.items() if v > something}
```

Comment: This is great! Could you explain the how the syntax of this actually works (like I'm five)?

Comment: @JesseO I just added enough explanation with enough doc links so that you either understand it (if you're a little fluent in python), or can work it out yourself.

Answer (score 22):

While nmaier's solution would have been my way to go, notice that since python 2.7+ there has been a "[dict comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)" syntax:

```
{k:v for (k,v) in dict.items() if v > something}
```

Found here: [Create a dictionary with list comprehension in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/python-create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension). I found this by googling "python dictionary list comprehension", top post.

#### Explanation

- `{ .... }` includes the dict comprehension
- `k:v` what elements to add to the dict
- `for (k,v) in dict.items()` this iterates over all tuples (key-value-pairs) of the dict
- `if v > something` a condition that has to apply on every value that is to be included

Comment: Guess I'm still "old school". :D

Comment: Yeah well, me too. I just learnt about that syntax myself. Pretty neat, actually.

Comment: I actually relearn that new syntax very couple of weeks myself :p

Comment: `dict.iteritems()`  would be slightly better.

Comment: I was wondering how fast this is if iterating over a dictionary with a couple million elements?

Answer (score 9):

You want `dict[i]` not `dict.values()`. `dict.values()` will return the whole list of values that are in the dictionary.

```
dict = {2:5, 6:2}
x = 4
print [dict[i] for i in dict if dict[i] >= x] # prints [5]
```

Comment: Nice one, exactly what I needed.