# Compute the average of all numbers in a list that are 50 or greater?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, average

I want to return a function which gives the average of all the marks which are `50` or more. When I run my code, it always returns an empty list.

Here is what I have tried:

```
def get_pass_average(marks):
    average = []
    for count in marks:
        if count >= 50:
           average = sum(count) / len(count)          
    return round(average,2)

def test_get_pass_average():
    list1 = [50, 83, 26, 65, 92, 29, 77, 64]
    print('%.2f' % (get_pass_average(list1)))
```

Please help me to figure out the problems in my code, and the output should be `71.83`.

Comment: For the question in title, OP can just [filter out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587915/return-list-of-items-in-list-greater-than-some-value) and [compute average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039961/finding-the-average-of-a-list). You don't need to provide the answer again.

Comment: Also remember to specify which Python version you're using, with a [tag:python-2.7] or [tag:python-3.x] tag. `/` behaves differently in both versions.

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
l=[i for i in list1 if i>=50]
print(sum(l)/len(l))
```

Or:

```
from statistics import mean
l=[i for i in list1 if i>=50]
print(mean(l))
```

If want to condition for empty lists:

```
l=[i for i in list1 if i>=50]
if l:
    print(sum(l)/len(l))
```

Or:

```
from statistics import mean
l=[i for i in list1 if i>=50]
if l:
    print(mean(l))
```

For python 2:

```
print(sum(l)/len(l))
```

Should be:

```
print(float(sum(l))/float(len(l)))
```

And no statistics module.

Your code doesn't work because you're summing the iterator (an integer) not the list so that's why it's not working

Answer (score 14):

In addition to U9-Forward's answer, one using `filter` and `mean`:

```
from statistics import mean

list1 = [50, 83, 26, 65, 92, 29, 77, 64]
average = mean(filter((50).__le__, list1))
print('%.2f' % average)
```

Comment: Nice too :-), thought me `__le__` :-)

Comment: Again (see comment on U9's answer), `le` should probably be `lt` (or whatever "less than" is).

Comment: I think the `op` module provides slightly more standard « operators as functions » if you’re interested.

Answer (score 11):

To answer the question of:

> Please helps me to figure out the problems in my code

The issue are the lines of:

```
for count in marks
    if count >= 50:
        average = sum( count ) / len( count )
```

`marks` is a list of integers. Hence, when you loop `for count in marks`, the value of `count` is an integer. I tested your code in both Python 3.6.3 and 2.7.10, and you can't even call the `sum()` and `len()` functions on an integer (they both return a `TypeError` if you try).

You initialize `average = []`, so it seems like you expect `average` to contain a list, but even if `sum( count ) = count` and `len( count ) = 1`, then `average` contains an integer, not a list.

I'd be to curious to know which version of Python you're using that allows this code to execute without error.

Corrections for these errors have already been given.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the code you provided does *not* return an empty list as you state, it actually asserts with a `TypeError`, assuming you actually *call* the `test_get_pass_average()` function, something that's not clear in your code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testprog.py", line 12, in <module>
    test_get_pass_average()
  File "testprog.py", line 10, in test_get_pass_average
    print('%.2f' % (get_pass_average(list1)))
  File "testprog.py", line 5, in get_pass_average
    average = sum(count) / len(count)          
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

It may be you're *assuming* it prints an empty list because there's no output but, unless you call the test function, there won't *be* any output, simply because the code you provide defines two functions but does nothing else.

The *reason* your code asserts (when you call it) is simply because you pass a non-iterable `int` variable to `sum()`. The `sum()` function requires an iterable since it iterates over each item to calculate the sum - you cannot iterate over a single integer (even if you *could,* the `len()` would fail because an `int` type has no such function:

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

And the reason you're trying to do this to an `int` is because the construct:

```
for variable in [3,1,4,1,5,9]:
```

will iterate over that list, setting `variable` to each element in turn. So `variable` will be an `int`, incapable of being subjected to either `sum()` or `len()`.

---

In terms of fixing it, the following function gives you a general solution to what you need, the average of all numbers greater than or equal to a certain threshold, and allowing a specific result if no numbers are available (defaults to `None`):

```
def AverageWithThreshold(myList, threshold, emptyResult = None):
    newList = [item for item in myList if item >= threshold]
    if len(newList) == 0: return emptyResult
    return sum(newList) / len(newList)
```

For your specific case, you can call it with something like (we assume the average of an empty list should be zero here):

```
print('%.2f' % (AverageWithThreshold(list1, 50, 0)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Almost everything else is covered, `filter` has a use here as well

```
l = list(filter(lambda x: x >= 50, marks))
print('%.2f' % (sum(l)/len(l)))
```

> ```
> 71.83
> ```

**To explain what's wrong with your code:**

- You're summing the the iterator (integer) for average.
- And also you're getting the length of it, where you can't because it's a integer.

Answer (score 1):

Store values and calculate the average later instead of trying to calculate the average inside for loop.

Hope you are looking for this:

```
def get_pass_average(marks):
    marksAbove = []
    for count in marks:
        if count >= 50:
            marksAbove.append(count);

    average = sum(marksAbove) / len(marksAbove)  
    return round(average,2)

def test_get_pass_average():
    list1 = [50, 83, 26, 65, 92, 29, 77, 64]
    print('%.2f' % (get_pass_average(list1)))

# Init
test_get_pass_average()
```