# How can I count elements of a list within a certain range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

i need to calculate how much numbers form string got value higher or equal to 25 and lower or equal to  50

```
numbers = [25, 24, 26, 45, 25, 23, 50, 51]

#  'count' should be 5 
count = 0
```

```
# I need to filter all numbers and only numbers what are higher than 25 can stay 

numbers = [25, 24, 26, 45, 25, 23, 50, 51]

#  'filtered' should be equal to [26, 45, 50, 51]
filtered = []
```

Comment: Nice problem! what have you tried so far?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I don't see anything related to an if statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return list of items in list greater than some value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587915/return-list-of-items-in-list-greater-than-some-value)

Comment: If your condition is `25 <= num <= 50`, then `filtered` must be `[25, 26, 45, 25, 50]`. Don't you agree?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I need to filter all numbers and only numbers what are higher than 25 can stay

you can use the built-in function `filter`:

```
numbers = [25, 24, 26, 45, 25, 23, 50, 51]
filtred = list(filter(lambda x : x > 25, numbers))
# [26, 45, 50, 51]
```

> how much numbers form string got value higher or equal to 25 and lower
>   or equal to 50

you can use the built-in function `sum`:

```
count = sum(1 for e in numbers if e >= 25 and e<= 50)
# 5
```

Comment: This should work too
`count = sum(1 for e in numbers if 25 < e < 51)`

Answer (score 6):

```
numbers = [25, 24, 26, 45, 25, 23, 50, 51]
count = len(numbers)
filtered = [num for num in numbers if 25 < num <= 50]
count -= len(filtered)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help

```
numbers = [25, 24, 26, 45, 25, 23, 50, 51]
count=0
f=[]
for i in numbers:
    if i>=25 and i<=50:
        f.append(i)
        count+=1
print(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it would be to create an empty list, iterate through the current list and append all relevant items to the new list, like so:

```
numbers = [25, 24, 26, 45, 25, 23, 50, 51]
new_list =[]

for i in numbers:
    if i>=25 and i<=50:
        new_list.append(i)

print(new_list)
```