# How to select elements in list based on last two characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list: `aa=["tea","tee","tea_N","tee_N"]`

I want to get the elements with last two characters are "_N".

The result is like: `["tea_N","tee_N"]`

How could I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter a list according to condition in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61326041/filter-a-list-according-to-condition-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

```py
list(filter(lambda x: x.endswith("_N"), aa))
```

See documentation for [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) and [`str.endswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith).

Equivalent list comprehension:

```py
[x for x in aa if x.endswith("_N")]
```

Comment: Don't use a `filter` when all you want is a list comprehension. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3013686/843953

Comment: May I ask how to get the elements based on two conditions? For example, I want to get the elements ending with "_N" or "ee"? So I the result is ["tee,"tea_N","tee_N"]

Comment: @Freeego You just add that check to the predicate `or x.endswith("ee")`.

Comment: It was a comment to OP and other readers telling them why to prefer a list comprehension over `filter`. Don't take things so personally

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Not at all. Just amusing how you simply state that as though it is the law instead of even hinting at a _reason_ or an _argument_ as to why we should use a list comprehension in place of `filter`. That post you linked is years old. Do you have recent benchmarks?

Comment: The comment includes a link to an answer that goes into more detail than I could possibly hope to in a comment. There are other, more recent answers there.

Comment: A quick test of your code on Py3.7.9 shows the list comprehension is 1.7x faster. I don't have access to a newer version to test, but I expect you'll see similar results